# Australian teen sci-fi series with high-tech shower removing hair dye which it considers as dirt in the person's hair

Tags: story-identification, tv

In the 90s I remember seeing a sci-fi series. It was a teen show with young actors and I think it was Australian.

I recall some kind of high-tech shower that removed hair dye because it considered it to be dirt/a contaminant in the girl's hair.

I think time travel was involved.

It was broadcast in the UK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [***The Girl from Tomorrow***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098803/) (1991), specifically Episode 1, Season 2 - *A Time Without Vegemite*

> **Jenny:** *The colour's gone!*
>
> **Alanna:** *The scanner thinks the dye's dirt and removes it.*
>
> **Jenny:** *At least I don't need a hair dryer.*

Comment: Great work, thanks!

Comment: @user - [Always a pleasure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)